# How to hide HTML calendar after adding JQuery datepicker in Firefox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

my problem is second calendar which is showing at the same time when first.Only on Firefox. 
I added JQuery datepicker to code to make calendar working on IOS and now on IOS is ok but on Firefox I got calendar from Jquery and basic HTML calendar from input type="date".

I would like to remove the HTML calendar in Firefox just like it is on other browsers and leave only JQuery calendar.

Thanks for help.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2m0Z.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7Cvw.png)

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <input type="date" class="calendar-delivery">

<script type="text/javascript">
       $(window).on('load', function () {
            if ( $('.calendar-delivery')[0].type = 'date' )
            {
                $('.calendar-delivery').datepicker(
                {
                    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                    minDate: -5,
                    maxDate: +5,       
                    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                    var day = date.getDay();
                    return [(day != 0), ''];
                    }
                }   
                );        
            }
         });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you've defined the picker on a `date` input. It needs to be used on a plain `text` input instead.

Also note that the condition which checks the field type in your JS should be removed. Partly because of the reason above, and also because the logic is broken. `=` is used to set a value, whereas `==` or `===` should be used to check equality.

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('.calendar-delivery').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    minDate: -5,
    maxDate: +5,
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var day = date.getDay();
      return [(day != 0), ''];
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input type="text" class="calendar-delivery">
```